# How to Identify a homogeneous first order first degree ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

The following equation is homogeneous edit: y dx - x dy + 3x^2y^2e^(x^3) dx = 0 (source: Wolfram alpha)
but it is not of the form of $f(zx,zy)= z(f(x,y))$. How do I identify such type of special Homogeneous equation that do not fit the definition?

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $t=xy $ we have $y'= \left(\frac{t}{y}\right)' =\frac{t'x -t}{x^2 }$ thus we have $$\frac{t'x -t}{x^2 } =y' =\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{y -y^3 x^2}{x+ x^3 y^2} =\frac{\frac{t}{x} -\frac{t^3}{x}}{xt^2 +x} =\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \frac{t-t^3}{t^2 +1}$$
hence
$$t'x -t =\frac{t-t^3}{t^2 +1}$$
and $$t'x =\frac{t-t^3 +t +t^3}{t^2 +1} =\frac{2t}{1+t^2} $$
therefore
$$\left( \frac{1}{2t} +\frac{1}{2} t\right)dt =\frac{dx}{x}$$
so the solution is $$\frac{1}{2}\ln |t| +\frac{1}{4} t^2 = \ln |x| +C$$

Comment: But How do I Check For it is Homogeneous or not? As the above equation is found to be Homogeneous it can be solved By Putting y=v*x.

Comment: It is not homogeneous in the sense that you're write above.

Comment: I got it , i actually posted the wrong question..... can you plz tell me to check homogeneous equations for such types :-  y dx - x dy + 3x^2y^2e^(x^3) dx = 0

Comment: If you have equation of the form $$P(x,y ) dx +Q(x,y ) dy =0$$ then it is homogenous if and only if the function $$\xi (x,y )=\frac{Q(x,y)}{P(x,y)}  $$ is homogenous i.e. $$\xi (tx,ty ) =\xi (x,y).$$